# xargs on windows: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, command-line, git, xargs

I wanted to resync the tags on my local git repository with the ones on our remote server, using [this answer provided on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373319/127497):

```
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
git fetch --tags
```

I've got git for windows portable installed which includes `xargs` from [FindUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm) (as best I can tell).

When I run the first part of the command, all I get is:

> xargs: git: No such file or directory

If I modify the command to run:

```
git tag -l | xargs echo
```

It correctly "echos" the tags for me. So, my only conclusion is that xargs for some reason can't resolve executables from the path.

How can I get xargs to properly execute what's passed to it (without resorting to passing the full path to `git.exe`?)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm seeing the same thing

Comment: Nope, never got to the bottom of it :-|

Comment: Running the exact command in git bash worked fine, so I went with that. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

I use the [Gnu on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) port of the Unix tools and get a similar problem to this but the error message is always `Invalid argument`, e.g.

```
> printf "Hello World!" | xargs printf "%s %s"
xargs: printf: Invalid argument
```

One solution appears to be to use the "proverbial" extra level of indirection, for example a shell such as `cmd.exe`, to actually invoke the command:

```
> printf "Hello World!" | xargs cmd /c printf "%s %s"
Hello World!
```